# Format JSON in right way from mysql database

Tags: php, json, pdo

I have this database:

[image]

I need to get this JSON output with php pdo:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "ID": "<div class=\"btn btn-danger\">1</div>",
            "naziv": "some data from database",
            "vrsta": "some data from database",
        },
        {
            "ID": "<div class=\"btn btn-danger\">2</div>",
            "naziv": "some data from database",
            "vrsta": "some data from database",
        }
    ]
}
```

So as you can see I need to modify data before JSON encoding...I need to add some html and css.

I try to do this with:

```
/* select all the weekly tasks from the table googlechart */
$result = $db->prepare('SELECT ID,naziv,vrsta FROM investicije');
$result->execute();

/* Extract the information from $result */
foreach($result as $r) {
    $temp = array();
    // the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart
    $temp['ID'] = '<div class="btn btn-danger">'.$r['ID'].'</div>'; 
    $temp['vrsta'] = $r['vrsta'];
    $temp['naziv'] = $r['naziv'];
}

$output = ['data' => $temp];
$jsonTable = json_encode($output);
```

This does not render the right JSON format as I put above.

UPDATE:

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "ajax": "table1.php",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "ID" },
            { "data": "naziv" },
            { "data": "vrsta" },

        ]
    } );
} );
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsitive" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Naziv</th>
                <th>Vrsta</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
               <th>ID</th>
                <th>Naziv</th>
                <th>Vrsta</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: As an aside, why mix straight data and HTML content in the same response.  Leave the HTML DOM element creation to the calling UI layer.

Comment: How I can do that? Is a bad practice to mix json with DOM data ?

Comment: So, I assume you are using `json_encode()` to send this data as response to a request (perhaps AJAX request), asa there would be no need to serialize it if just some other area of the PHP application needed it.  Assuming this assumption is correct, then there is obviously some other place where you are presenting the rest of the HTML for the page.  Why would you want to "hide" a portion of that page implementation within a PHP script that is simply being used to retrieve data from a database?  Now if you want to change the class on the div for example, you would have to modify the PHP script.

Comment: This is as opposed to simply passing the ID value with your data and letting the caller put this within the contextg of a DOM element. All your display logic would be in one place with this approach, and this script can simply worry about retrieving the requested data.

Comment: some totorial to help me to create UI layer ?

Comment: You should perhaps open a new question that shows your pertinent HTML code and javascript (again assuming you are using AJAX here) within which you can talk about what you are looking to do.

Comment: I will update question with HTML and JS

Comment: THE QUESTION IS UPDATED...

Comment: You should really open a separate question, as this topic is really unrelated to your initial question. Knowing now that you are using dataTables, my guess is you should experiment with columns option to add the div wrapper around the received data for rendering.  See documentation here - http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Comment: There is an example of creating a link from the data source during render. This is basically exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are overwriting your `$temp` variable without using it. You need to move `$output = ['data' => $temp];` into the foreach loop and change it a bit:

```
foreach($result as $r) {
    $temp = array();
    // the following line will be used to slice the Pie chart
    $temp['ID'] = '<div class="btn btn-danger">'.$r['ID'].'</div>'; 
    $temp['vrsta'] = $r['vrsta'];
    $temp['naziv'] = $r['naziv'];

    $output['data'][] = $temp;
}
```

Comment: thanks that right, thanks very much. Is a bad practice to mix html and data in JSON and how to solve this?

Comment: @JamesD. Normally you shouldn't have to store html in the database; if you use the returned json in javascript, you can build the html there as you see fit using just the data.

Comment: But I dont store html in database , I add html only in JSON ... as you can see from mysql database above in a image

Comment: @JamesD. I don't really see a problem, but if you really want to nitpick, you could argue that you are sending more data than necessary; you could only send the values and build the html in javascript. And if you want to change your html structure, you would need to do that in more places than strictly necessary. But if it works for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting your `$temp` array on every iteration of the loop. You probably want:

```
foreach($result as $r) {
    $temp[] = array(....);
         ^^---array push shorthand;
}
```

instead.